# Python custom module installalation won't copy static files

Tags: python-2.7, setuptools, python-module, pypi

hi I'm developing a python module and when I create the install package using `python setup.py sdist bdist_egg` all the files are included on the zip file, but when I run `python setup.py install` all files are copied except the static files. 
the full project is on:

https://github.com/efirvida/python-gearbox

my setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
version = '0.1.0a'
setup(
    name='python-gearbox',
    version=version,
    author='Eduardo M. Firvida Donestevez',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_data_package=True,
    author_email='efirvida@gmail.com',
    description='Python library for gear transmission design',
    requires=['numpy', 'scipy'],
    url='https://github.com/efirvida/python-gearbox',
    download_url='https://github.com/efirvida/python-gearbox/archive/master.zip',
    keywords=['gearbox', 'gear', 'agma', 'iso', 'gear transmission', 'engineering'],
    platforms='any',
    license='MIT',
    zip_safe=False,
    classifiers=['Intended Audience :: Developers',
             'Intended Audience :: Manufacturing',
             'Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
             'Natural Language :: English',
             'Programming Language :: Python',
             'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
             'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering',
             'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Human Machine Interfaces',
             'Topic :: Software Development',
             'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries',
             'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Application Frameworks'
             ]
)
```

Comment: What is precisely the static file your are talking about?

Comment: the module have a folder `gearbox\export\templates` on this folder are 3 file xxx.template when running the installation this files are not copied to the module `site-package/<module folder>` or even the build folder, but their are on the zip installation file crated by `python setup.py sdist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got this. In your `setup.py` change

```
 include_data_package=True,
```

into:

```
 include_package_data=True
```

If you look at the log when doing `python setup.py install`, you'll find the clue:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: 
UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'include_data_package'
```

Besides, I also made some modifications to the `MANIFEST.in`, to make it clearer:

```
include Makefile CHANGES LICENSE AUTHORS README 
recursive-include gearbox/doc/source *.rst
recursive-include gearbox/export/templates *
recursive-exclude gearbox *.pyc
```

Comment: Happy to help. Reviewing the log is always a good way in debugging.